# retrieving datetime from mysql in time.time in golang

Tags: mysql, go

i have stored on my database (mySQL) this datatime field, last_activity: `2017-06-12 11:07:09`

im using the param `parseTime=True` on my OpenDB

the problem is that the output is: `last activity: {63632862429 0 <nil>}`
instead of `2017-06-12 11:07:09`

what am i doing wrong?

thanks

```
type DateType time.Time

type User struct {
    LastActivity DateType
}


func (stUser *User) GetUserDataByLogin(login string) {

db := OpenDB()

defer db.Close()

// Test the connection to the database
err := db.Ping()
checkErr(err)

err = db.QueryRow("SELECT  last_activity FROM users WHERE login = ?", login).Scan(&stUser.LastActivity)

if err != nil {
    if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
        // there were no rows, but otherwise no error occurred
    } else {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

fmt.Println("last activity:", stUser.LastActivity)
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You must declare `DateType.String()` method like this:

```
func (t DateType) String() string {
    return time.Time(t).String()
}
```

From [Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations):

> The declared type does not inherit any methods bound to the existing type

Answer (score 0):

`time.Time` is a nullable type. You got to anticipate that and use somethink like the pq package and the `NullTime` type instead of `time.Time`.
cf : https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#NullTime

`pq.NullTime` is a structure :

```
type NullTime struct {
    Time  time.Time
    Valid bool // Valid is true if Time is not NULL
}
```

If `Valid` is `True` then you'll got a result in `Time`.